# Internal error -- WebRTC publisher error & Internal error -- WebRTC subscriber error

Tags: android, webrtc, opentok

We are trying to add Voip (no video) to our Android application using OpenTok. We are seeing issues when a 3rd user joins a session and when a user leaves and rejoins a session.

Example:
A session is created. User1 and User2 join.. both can hear each other talking. When User3 joins, we get multiple errors (shown below). As a result, sometimes one user can hear but not talk and other times one user will not be able to hear or talk... or a combination of the two. Who gets the error seems to be random but there does seem to be a correlation between who gets the error and who can talk/hear.

---

SubscriberListener onError()

message: Internal error -- WebRTC publisher error.

errorName: PublisherWebRTCError

errorCode: 1610

---

SubscriberListener onError()

message: Internal error -- WebRTC subscriber error.

errorName: SubscriberWebRTCError

errorCode: 1600

---

Devices:
All Nexus 7 running 4.4.2

OpenTok Android SDK Version:
2.2

Comment: Also, we tested the samples at https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples and they worked on the same devices.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something with your code. Since you did not post any code, I will try to generalize.

When the first user joins, Session.SessionListener's `onStreamReceived` will get called with a stream object parameter. To subscribe to that stream, you call
`subscriber = session.subscribe(stream..)`

To subscribe to multiple users, you might want to keep an array of subscriber objects every time you call session.subscribe method.

If that doesn't help, you might be in a mesh p2p session. Under certain network conditions (firewall or router configurations), webRTC will fail over mesh. The safest route is to use mediaRouted flag when you create sessions, or to make sure all your test devices are on the same wifi network: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-node#creating-sessions

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same problem on iOS. Here is how we subscribed

```
- (void)session:(OTSession *)session streamCreated:(OTStream *)stream
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (![self.streamID isEqualToString:stream.streamId])
    {
        self.tokBoxSubcriber = [[OTSubscriber alloc] initWithStream:stream delegate:self];
        self.tokBoxSubcriber.subscribeToAudio = YES;
        self.tokBoxSubcriber.subscribeToVideo = NO;

        [self.tokBoxSession subscribe:self.tokBoxSubcriber error:nil];
    }
 }
```

Here is how we published

```
- (void)sessionDidConnect:(OTSession *)session
{
    self.tokBoxPublisher = [[OTPublisher alloc] initWithDelegate:self name:@"publisher"];
    self.tokBoxPublisher.publishAudio = YES;
    self.tokBoxPublisher.publishVideo = NO;

    OTError *error;
    [self.tokBoxSession publish:self.tokBoxPublisher error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    }

    [self.delegate connectedToVoIP:self];
}
```